# Moving GroupBys

Tags: python-2.7, numpy, apache-spark, pyspark

My Data Set Looks like

```
1
2
3
4
5
...
```

I have an intermediate step which should do the folowing

```
1
1,2
1,2,3
1,2,3,4
1,2,3,4,5
....
```

And finally calculate its mean

```
1
1.5
2
2.5
3
...
```

Questions
a) Is there a way to implement this in python / py-spark?.
b) Is there a method/api which does this out of the box.
c) I googled around for this kind of solution the closest i got was to moving mean/ rolling average / moving group. Is there a term for this operation?

Comment: what do you mean 'calculate it's mean'? are you calculating the mean of each line? (if so you've made a mistake with your math)

Comment: Sorry for the typo max

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Pandas, this is called an `expanding_mean`:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.Series(range(1,6))
s = pd.Series(range(1,6))
pd.expanding_mean(s)
Out[128]: 
0    1.0
1    1.5
2    2.0
3    2.5
4    3.0
dtype: float64
```

I'm not sure how you'd do this in Spark, but that said, I'm also not sure if this is a "parallelalizable" task: since each step relies on the previous step, I'm not sure how you'd break this up into steps.

Comment: Is there a way to do this in spark. Can we parallelize this operation?.